# mysql count of a column based on date and type

Tags: mysql, query, group-by, sum

I have the following table optimizations

```
select items_type,
       created_at,
       count_optimized_items 
from optimizations 
where shop_id=126 
and count_optimized_items!=0
```

| items_type | created_at | count_optimized_items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2023-04-20 06:49:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-04-20 06:49:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-04-20 06:48:59 | 50 |
| 5 | 2023-04-20 06:48:59 | 170 |
| 5 | 2023-04-21 07:00:42 | 212 |
| 5 | 2023-04-20 07:14:54 | 147 |
| 5 | 2023-04-20 07:25:31 | 210 |
| 5 | 2023-04-20 07:39:33 | 193 |
| 5 | 2023-04-20 07:52:41 | 102 |

Now I want to group by and get sum of count_optimized_irems according to items_type and date

```
select name,
       shop_id,
       items_type,
       created_at,
       count_optimized_items,
       sum(count_optimized_items) as sum_count 
from metadata_optimizations 
where shop_id=126 
and count_optimized_items!=0 
group by created_at,items_type
```

I tried the above query but it does not work

this is the expected result

| items_type | created_at | count_optimized_items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2023-04-20 06:49:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-04-20 06:49:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-04-20 06:48:59 | 50 |
| 5 | 2023-04-20 06:48:59 | 822 |
| 5 | 2023-04-21 07:00:42 | 212 |

basically sum of count_optimized_items based on date and items type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stands in the group by part. You need to group by DATE(created_at).

Consider the following data example which can be found in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BQURHe2N) as well

```
create table optimizations (
  items_type int,
  created_at timestamp ,
  count_optimized_items int );

insert into optimizations values
(4,'2023-04-20 06:49:00',1),
(2,'2023-04-20 06:49:00',1),
(1,'2023-04-20 06:48:59',50),
(5,'2023-04-20 06:48:59',170),
(5,'2023-04-21 07:00:42',212),
(5,'2023-04-20 07:14:54',147),
(5,'2023-04-20 07:25:31',210),
(5,'2023-04-20 07:39:33',193),
(5,'2023-04-20 07:52:41',102);
```

Query,

```
select items_type,
       DATE(created_at) as dt,
       sum(count_optimized_items) AS count_optimized_items_sum
from optimizations
group by  items_type, DATE(created_at);
```

With the other conditions the final query would look as follows

```
select min(name) as name,
       min(shop_id) as shop_id,
       items_type,
       DATE(created_at) as created_at,
       sum(count_optimized_items) as sum_count 
from metadata_optimizations 
where shop_id=126 
and count_optimized_items !=0 
group by DATE(created_at),items_type
```